# How to give virtual directory path in application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, virtual-directory

I have a virtual directory in IIS just under the application folder like

```
MyApplication/VirtualDirectory
```

[image: Folder structure in IIS (Please ignore naming convention as it just for representation purpose here)]

I wish to access this VirtualDirectory in my application, things that I've tried are like :

```
string[] imageDir = null;
string sourceFilePath = "Myapplication/VirtualDirectory"; 
/* ./Myapplication/VirtualDirectory
~/Myapplication/VirtualDirectory
\Myapplication/VirtualDirectory
.\Myapplication/VirtualDirectory
~\Myapplication/VirtualDirectory*/
imageDir = Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath);
```

Please let me know if any additional data is needed, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] imageDir = null;
string sourceFilePath = "~/VirtualDirectory";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code, and you need to use [ServerManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager?view=iis-dotnet) Class.

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
 // get the site (e.g. default)
Site site = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Default Web Site");
 // get the application that you are interested in
Application myApp = site.Applications["/Dev1"];
 // get the physical path of the virtual directory
Console.WriteLine(myApp.VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath);
```